# update row based on number of times a row appears in Sqlite

Tags: sqlite

So I have 4 columns: id, name, name_id, count.

The first 3 columns are completely filled out. However, I would like to know how to update the count of each row to be the number of times the name_id occurs.

So if we have 2 b's and 1 "c", then we have:

```
0 "b" 3 2 
4 "b" 3 2
3 "c" 4 1
```

I can't seem to get any sqlite command to do what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update your_table t1
inner join 
(
   select name, count(*) as namecount
   from your_table
   group by name
) t2 on t1.name = t2.name
set `count` = namecount
```

Comment: what is the * for? What is this command doing? I'm trying to learn sql(ite) and I don't see what this is doing.

Comment: The inner select outputs each name and the count of it using `count(*)` which counts all rows af each name. That result is joined to the update statement to set the count